# Como importar un caracter 3D en una aplicación android

Tags: android, 3d

Necesito crear un aplicación para android que muestre un caracter en 3D. Qué formato o especificación necesita mi caracter 3d para que lo pueda usar en mi app.

Comment: Sí disculpa. Preguntaba qué software me recomendarían para crear un caracter en 3D para una aplicación android. Necesito que sea responsive cuando se toca etc etc .. algo así como un avatar

Comment: [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) es gratuito y se compara con los mejores de programas de pago o puedes bajar gratuito alguno de [Turbosquid](http://www.turbosquid.com)

Comment: La pregunta está redactada en inglés

Comment: Hola isccha89 Las preguntas sobre recomendaciones de software son consideradas offtopic en Stack Overflow.

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz creo que puedo salvarla con un edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar [Rajawali](https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali) para importar tu modelo 3D en los siguientes formatos `.obj`, `.md2`, `.3ds` y `.fbx`

Desde [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) puedes exportar modelos `.obj`, `.3ds` y `.fbx`, este software es gratuito y se compara con los mejores de programas de pago o puedes bajar gratuito alguno de [Turbosquid](http://www.turbosquid.com) filtrando por el formato `.obj`, `.md2`, `.3ds` y `.fbx`

Puedes buscar tambien en http://www.blendswap.com/ donde hay modelos para blender y puedes realizar el proceso de exportación del modelo, para posteriormente usarlo en tu app.

Aqui un ejemplo de lo que puedes realizar en blender:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y como exportar el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y para incluirlo en tu app puedes leer [esto](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html) o [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8420843/3100840) hay otra lista de opciones

Comment: @isccha89 Ahora debes de tener en cuenta que aprender a usar blender (o algun otro programa de edicion 3d) no es tan facil, existe una gran curva de aprendizaje, para poder hacer algo como lo de la imagen, pero no hay nada que con esfuerzo no se pueda, agrego otro sitio donde puedes descargas modelos gratis para blender y puedas realizar el proceso de exportación para despues importar en tu app

Comment: @isccha89 quiero hacerle unas preguntas y a la vez quizas le ayude, usted dice que quieres importar un modelo 3d para usar en su app, primero quiere introducir el modelo para simplemente tenerlo ahi con simplemente me refiero a que rote el objeto y poco mas, y a la misma vez quiere usar los widget que le proporciona android los gridview los datepicker ect, pues si es asi, siga el camino atravez de GLSurfaceView o similares. Si por otro lado usted lo que quiere es crear un juego, nada de widget de los mencionados anteriormente ni nada de eso, puede barajar la opcion de usar algun engine

Comment: o libreria para crea el juego que le facilitara la tarea (muho). Si ha decidido que lo que quiere es un juego (juego no hablo de un cubo dando vueltas), yo le recomendaria que buscase algun engine, por ejemplo si usted maneja java es muy comun el uso de LIBGdx, si usa C# Unity3d, pero creo que sabiendo un algo de java podria probar Unity3d, porque cuenta con mas documentacion y tutoriales que lo ayudaran para hacer su juego aprendiendo mientras avanza, si sabe java y usa LIBGdx puede que pase bastante tiempo solucionado y buscado informacion de como usar, si sabe java y usa

Comment: Unity pues el tiempo que inviertes en aprender como hacer algo en C# te lo ahorras a la hora buscar informacion sobre como hacer algo en concreto, ademas de Unity es mucho mas comodo de trabajar, probar el juego, hacer cambios ect. en fin si te preguntas que estoy a favor de Unity antes de LIBGdx, pues la verdad es que no, todo dependeria de muchos factores el elegir uno u otro en mi caso, pero en este contexto creo que le iria mejor Unity, solo tiene que ir a youtube y poner tutoriales de uno u otro y vera la diferencia en cuanto a informacion y lo que ello implica, si decide LIBGdx

Comment: tambien es buena eleccion. espero le ayude Saludos

Comment: Claro, demasiadas gracias por la ayuda!